# I can't see HellowWorldFlow in the Processes menu and Process menu is inactive

Tags: django-viewflow

I have done all the steps for the quick start twice. 
I have tried Django 2.2.9 and 3.0.2. 
I have a `127.0.0.1:8000/workflow/` page. 
I can change language and theme color. 
Admin-panel does work too.

What did I miss, please?

p.s. maybe you should make the 'django-viewflow' tag for ru.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: That's hard to say what happens in your case. Check that you correctly added app to the INSTALLED_APPS settings and run migration. Check that your user has all required permissions.

Comment: Dear Mikhail, the application and all migrations was added according to your instructions and the super-admin user should have all rights by default, but I added all rights to him forcibly.

Comment: did you register the flow to the frontend? @frontend.register